# How to use cellcolor and double backslash

Tags: tables, line-breaking, cellcolor

This is my code which fails on the last row in the tabular. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
    a \\ b \tabularnewline
    \cellcolor{blue}{a b}   \tabularnewline
    \cellcolor{green}{a \\ b}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `a\\b` is two cells on two rows, you can't have them in a single cell (so can not be in a  cellcolor argument)

Comment: Oh well. (La)TeX's table model surprises me every day again.

Comment: `\cellcolor` only has one argument, not two, `\cellcolor{green}` means "make this cell green`   so the extra braces `{a\\b}`  would generate an error even without the colour commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```latex
\cellcolor{green}{a \\
```

does:

- `\cellcolor{green}` followed by
- an explicit begin-group token that starts a new group (opening brace `{` with category code 1)
- adds an `a` character
- ends the `tabular` row with `\\`

At this point, this is incorrect because the `\\` terminates the cell that was being processed, but begin-group end end-group tokens are not properly balanced inside this cell (a group was started by the `{` but not properly ended by your code). This is why TeX says:

```
./rr.tex:10: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.10     \cellcolor{green}{a \\ b
                                 }
```

(AFAIK, it says this *after* reading `b` because `\\` did some lookahead to see if you gave an optional argument, before issuing a `\cr`).

Besides, and this is why I wrote this answer, `\cellcolor` **takes only one argument**, not two, thus I would write this to fix your example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
    a \\
    b \\
    \cellcolor{blue!20}a b\\
    \cellcolor{green!20}a\\
    \cellcolor{green!20}b
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(`xcolor` is only used to have colors that are nicer on the eyes than just `blue` and `green`)

[image]

Comment: This gives me insight on what is going wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because that line has more than one cell. This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
    \\ b \tabularnewline
    \cellcolor{blue}{a b}   \tabularnewline
    \cellcolor{green}{a} \\ \cellcolor{green}{b}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I apologize for setting the other answer as "the answer", but it helped me slightly more understanding the problem. But thank you for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

> Oh well. (La)TeX's table model surprises me every day again.

I think the new [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package will surprise you for another time. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{l}
  a \\ b \\
  \SetCell{blue8} a b \\
  \SetCell{teal8} {a \\ b}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can put in a cell a multi-row content with the versatile built-in command `\Block` which has a key `fill` to fill it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{l}[colortbl-like]
    a \\ 
    b \\
    \cellcolor{blue!15}a b \\
    \Block[fill=green!15]{}{a \\ b}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]