# Two cells in one cellcolor argument

Tags: tables, line-breaking, colortbl

This is a follow-up to my previous question [How to use cellcolor and double backslash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520790/243) - is there any way to do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
  \cellcolor{green}{a \\ b}
\end{tabular}
```

Without repeating the `\cellcolor{green}{...}` for each new cell?

The reason is that I create the table programatically and it difficult to detect newlines.

Comment: If all cells in the column have the same colour, you can use in the table preamble `\begin{table}{\columncolor{green}l}`.

Comment: Have a look at cellprops. Then you can use css-selectors for the cells (maybe that fits your use-case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can defining a new command be an option?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\twocell[2]{\cellcolor{#1}{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}}

\begin{tabular}{l}
  \twocell{green}{a \\ b}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is almost what I do now. I use `\parbox[t]{width}{..\\..}` for the text. Thank you for the pointer!